# How to get string from xml data using lua script

Tags: xml, lua, speech-recognition, grammar, freeswitch

I am using lua script for getting data from xml files. From my code, I got a result in xml format. Now I need to check the xml file for some words that are available or not in that result, so I used this line

```
_,_,pre,result,suf = string.find (xml,"(.*)".. asrtag.. ": (.*)(.*)")
```

but this line shows

> attempt to concatenate global'result' (a nil value) stack traceback:

this error ... one important thing to add it is NLSML type xml

Comment: Where is `string.discover` defined? That's not a standard library function.

Comment: sorry, string.find

Comment: Paste full code and return result value then might be able to help.